# How to add bandpass filter to recorded sound in matlab

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, sound

I have a sound that is being recorded but I am trying to apply bandpass filtering to the sound so that it filters out anything above and below a selected frequency range. I have tried the tool in matlab to create the filter but for some reason can not get it to work. The code below is the record portion that I have the sound being recorded but need help applying the filter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function soundRecord (signal)
fs = 44100; %Sample Frequency
f = 15:22; %Frequency range
recObj = audiorecorder(44100, 16, 2);
get(recObj)

%save sound to wave file
%filename = 'location.flac';
audiowrite('input.wav',signal, fs);


if ~exist('inFile')
inFile = 'input.wav';
end

if ~exist('outFile')
outFile = 'output.wav';
end

if ~exist('frameWidth')
frameWidth = 4096;          % size of FFT frame, better be a power of 2
end
frameHop = frameWidth/2;

 analWindow = hanning(frameWidth);

 [inBuffer, Fs] = wavread(inFile);

 for arrayCol = 1:2
 % if(arrayCol == 1)
 %     x = [inBuffer(:,arrayCol); linspace(0, 0, frameWidth)'];                   %     `    left channel passed through, zeropad one frame at the end`
 % end
 %if(arrayCol==2)
    x = inBuffer(:,arrayCol);
    %x = inBuffer;                   % left channel passed through, zeropad one frame `    at the end`
%end
%clear inBuffer;

numSamples = length(x);

numFrames = floor(numSamples/frameHop)-1;

% disp(frameWidth);
% disp(numSamples);
% disp(frameHop);
% disp(numFrames);
% disp(size(analWindow));
% disp(size(transpose(analWindow)));

y = linspace(0, 0, numSamples)';


n = 0;                              % init sample pointer.  unlike MATLAB, i like `   counting from 0`

for frameIndex = 1:numFrames



     xWindowed = x(n+1:n+frameWidth) .* analWindow;     % get and window the input        `    audio frame`

     X = fft(fftshift(xWindowed));              % do the FFT

     Y = X;                         % copy the input spectrum to output

                                % do whatever processing to Y that you like

     yWindowed = fftshift(real(ifft(Y)));           % convert back to time domain,           `    toss the imaginary part`

     %disp(size(x(1:frameWidth)));
     %disp(size(yWindowed));

     y(n+1:n+frameWidth) = y(n+1:n+frameWidth) + yWindowed;

     n = n + frameHop;
%spectrogram(X,256,250,f,1E3,'yaxis');
%surf(f,10*log10(abs(p)),'EdgeColor','none'); 
%axis xy; axis tight; colormap(jet); view(0,90);
%xlabel('Time');grid on;
%ylabel('Frequency (Hz)');grid on;

pwelch(X);grid on;
end

soundArray(:,arrayCol) = y;

end    

%wavwrite(y, Fs, 'output.wav');
wavwrite(soundArray, Fs, 'output.wav');
```

Comment: Have you tried `fir1`?